# use makefile to parallelize bash script

Tags: bash, makefile

I have some .src files, and I want to render **ONE** .png file given **A** .src files.
That is, every .src file can be rendered **independently**.

I used to write a bash script using loop. But this loop can not be executed parallel.

So I want to write a makefile and make use of 'make -jN'.

The question is, what is the target in my makefile?
(I tried this;
%.png : %.src
    cat $<
but it does not work)

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.  Surely `cat`ting files together won't produce a PNG file?

Comment: I put a 'cat' there just for a placeholder. sorry for the confused statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a rule that lists all generated files as dependencies. When using GNU make, that could be

```
all: $(subst .src,.png,$(wildcard *.src))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute bash commands in a loop in parallel:

```
for i in {1..10} ; do sleep 10 & done ; echo Waiting ; time wait
```